# How can I create a specific-sized random number based on the row of the table using PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a specific-sized random "key" for every row in the database table. For example, for the "id" or row (auto-increment ID) "20", the column "key" will have "xEd456" and for row 21, it will be e.g. "rYU875". However, I also want to make sure there is no way there is a duplicate "key" in the table. I prefer to have 6-char "key". How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why? What are you *really* trying to accomplish (what problem are you trying to solve)?

Comment: create hex code of each auto increment id and select any 6 characters and save it in your DB.

Comment: Many PHP random string generation functions are available. Try to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you need a alphanumeric key, see the code

```
while(true)
  {
  $str="";
  for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
    {
    $rnd=rand(1,16);
    if(intval(fmod($rnd, 2)))
    $a=rand(48,57);
    else
    $a=rand(65,90);
    $str .= chr($a);
    }
  // skipping the mysql connection functions
  $sql=mysql_query(“select user_id from user_master_table where user_id_alias='".$str."'");
  $rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
  if($rs["user_id"]=="")
    break;
  }
```

You are free to change the loop value and random number range.